# How to compare a number with count result then use it in limit statement in redshift/sql

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I have a table with two columns `id` and `flag`.
The data is very imbalanced. Only a few `flag` has value `1` and others are `0`.

```
id flag
1   0
2   0
3   0
4   0
5   1
6   1
7   0
```

Now I want to create a balanced table. Therefore, I want get a subset from `flag = 0` based on the number of records where `flag = 1`. Also, I don't want the number to be greater than 1000.

I am thinking about a code like this:

```
select *
from table
where flag = 0
order by random()
limit (least(1000, 
             select count(*) 
             from table 
             where flag = 1));
```

Expected result(Only two records have `flag` as 1 so I get two records with `flag` as 0, if there are more than 1000 records have `flag` as 1 I will only get 1000.):

```
id flag
2   0
7   0
```

Comment: Could you provide some sample data and expect result?

Comment: @D-Shih Just edit the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want a balanced sample:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*, row_number() over (partition by flag order by flag) as seqnum,
             sum(case when flag = 1 then 1 else 0 end) over () as cnt_1
      from t
     ) t
where seqnum <= cnt_1;
```

You can change this to:

```
where seqnum <= least(cnt_1, 1000)
```

If you want an overall maximum.

Comment: `partition by flag order by flag` or `partition by flag order by random()`?

Comment: Order by flag! since all you flag values (say 0) is the same, it will order in a random fashion.

Comment: @Harold . . . I'm not sure if Redshift requires the `order by`.  Some databases do, some don't.  I always put one it.

Comment: @RahulGupta . . . The resulting ordering is *indeterminate* but not necessarily *random*.

Answer (score 0):

You can use row_number to simulate LIMIT.

```
select * from (
select column1, column2, row_number() OVER() AS rownum
from table
where flag = 0 )
where rownum < 1000
```

If I’ve made a bad assumption please comment and I’ll refocus my answer.

Comment: Hi Rahul, thanks. Instead of the first 1000, I want random 1000 rows. Should I change row_number() to other functions?

Comment: I was about to edit my answer, but Gordon got it. His solution should work.